# Transform in meta-predicate at prolog

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

I have been reading and noticed that predicates like *call* are called meta-predicates and they can return other predicates as a result (Don't know if return is a good use of the word here) for example here:

```
assert(call(goal, X,Y)).
```

Edit: lurker called me to reason, this doesn't work.

I understand that it's not supposed to call predicates functions but is there a way of making assert over a predicate that will  be unknown until runtime?

I want to use the same insertion predicate for more than one fact , so assert(fact(X)) does not suit my needs. I can retrieve the fact's name on runtime but how could i use assert without unifying a fact directly?

Comment: When you say that `assert(call(goal, X, Y)).` *will work* what does that mean? Work in what way? What I see happening is an attempt to assert `call(...)` would result in an error attempting to modify an existing Prolog procedure (`call`).

Comment: @lurker you are very right my friend, i am so tired that i imagined i saw it work. Is there a way of making assert without previous knowing of the predicate of which is needed the assert? i will modify my question. I am sorry

Comment: No worries. On to the question at hand: a predicate is just a *term* right? It looks like `':-'(head, body)`. So you can do `assertz(':-'(Head, Body)).` where `Head` and `Body` are instantiated at run time. You can also write it as `assertz((Head :- Body)).` since `:-` is an operator. Note that `Head` and `Body` should be istantiated at the time of the `assertz/1` call.

Comment: Lurker, i will try your approach, i am really enjoying the language. Thank you for your input, it certainly helps to progress .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly use `assertz/1` or `asserta/1`. `assert/1` is an alias for `assertz/1` but only in some Prolog systems.

The call:

```
assertz(call(goal, X, Y)).
```

will attempt to assert a *fact* with functor `call`. This is what it tries to assert in the database:

```
call(goal, _, _).
```

Since `call` is a functor already defined in Prolog as a predicate, it will generate an error. If you were to assert, say, the following:

```
assertz(foo(goal, X, Y)).
```

It would be successful, but what you'd get in the database is something like this:

```
foo(goal, _, _).
```

Which doesn't seem very useful. In other words, the assert is just doing what you asked it: asserting a *term* that you just described whose functor is `call` or `foo` in the above cases.

If you want to assert an actual predicate, you just need to use the fact that a predicate is a *term* whose functor is `:-`. The general predicate term would be something like `Head :- Body` or, in canonical form, `':-'(Head, Body)`. This kind of term can be asserted, as long as at least `Head` is instantiated before the `assertz` call.

```
assertz(':-'(Head, Body)).
```

Or equivalently (since `:-` is an operator):

```
assertz((Head :- Body)).
```

If I do this:

```
Head = goal, assertz((Head :- Body)).
```

I get (using `listing/0`):

```
:- listing.

goal :-
    call(_).
```

Not very useful. So `Body` really should be instantiated before making this `assertz/1` call. Here then is another example:

```
Head = double(X, Y), Body = (Y is X * 2), assertz((Head :- Body)).
```

Which now results in the following:

```
:- listing.

double(A, B) :-
        B is A * 2.
```

Comment: as always, great explanations and to the point. Thank you so much.